# ReferenceError when using external library in angular 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular1.6

I am writing simple app using Java and Angular 1.6. For dependency management I am using webjars defined in pom.xml.
I am trying to use flatpickr (js library) and Angular-flatpickr. 
I added two lines in index.html file: (in this order)

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
<script src="webjars/angular-flatpickr/2.0.0/dist/ng-flatpickr.js"></script>
```

Next I added line like this:

```
var module = angular.module('atApp.somemodule', [
'angular-flatpickr' 
]);
```

And settings:

```
$scope.dateOpts = {
    dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
    defaultDate: '2016-03-01 03:30:00 -0300'
};

$scope.datePostSetup = function(fpItem) {
    console.log('flatpickr', fpItem);
}
```

And I try to use it:

```
<input ng-flatpickr fp-opts="dateOpts" fp-on-setup="datePostSetup(fpItem)" ng-model="date.selectedDateObj" data-enabletime="true">
```

Then I get:

```
ReferenceError: Flatpickr is not defined
    at Object.link (ng-flatpickr.js:18)
    at angular.js:1351
    at angular.js:10694
    at invokeLinkFn (angular.js:10700)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:10077)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9350)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9353)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:10071)
    at angular.js:10416
    at processQueue (angular.js:17374) "<input ng-flatpickr="" fp-opts="dateOpts" fp-on-setup="datePostSetup(fpItem)" ng-model="date.selectedDateObj" data-enabletime="true" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope">"
```

Is there something that I missed? (I'm new in javascript). I read about using 'require' and 'import' but It's probably not way to go.

Answer (score -1):

You have versions mismatch. Try to use ng-flatpickr v3.0.0

Comment: Thanks! It was problem with version. I replace previous flatpickr script with the one downloaded by maven (because this dependency is downloaded too) and now it works.